# How to run screen using bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I am developing an application on Linux CentOS server. I need to automatically after registration of each use server create a screen to run some codes in loop for user.

When I use bash script to create new screen, it can't open screen and run commands in that screen.

For example, I want to open an screen and I run a php file in that screen. I have created a bash script test.sh but when I run this using cron tab it doesn't work.

```sh
screen
php php.php
```

Please tell what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Why are you tagging this by _cron_? There is nothing related to `cron` in your question, and I hope very much that you are not going to start `screen` as a cron-job.

Comment: Because I am running bash script using crontab

Comment: But you can't start a screen session from a crontab! You don't have a terminal!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do this and such a thread [already exists](https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach).

```
screen -d -m yourcommand
```